# SharePoint 2013 Site Redirect

Tags: 2013, redirect, dns

I have a request that if user types SharePoint in the browser it should take them to our SharePoint Landing page say http://sharepoint.com which is basically the root site. Do i need to make an alias in DNS?

Our Root Site basically acts as a Landing Page where we have all FAQ's and How To and Wikis stuff. Thank You

Comment: i think if you create a DNS alias whihc points to SharePoint.com and also Update the AAM settings then it will work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the alias in the DNS server with either the static IP or base IP of the SharePoint Web server.

Then add the bindings with port 80 and the IP. if the server has only IP assigned  then you may use unassigned mapping as well.

Also, add the AAM mappings to the required zone based on the type of configuration/authentication approaches.

Comment: what if I have one loadbalancer and 4 WebApps would the alias will have that loadbalancers IP address?